# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de login con conexión a una base de datos de un cliente, pero al momento de confirmar el usuario y contraseña manda este error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

En el código de confirmación puse collate utf8_bin ... esto me había funcionado anteriormente en consultas con bases locales.

Aquí esta el código de la consulta:

```
String Consulta = "select * from usuarios where Usuario ='" + user + "' collate utf8_bin and Contrasena ='" + pass + "' collate utf8_bin";
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que tu base de datos tiene collation utf8_bin o no latin1?

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en qué el `COLLATE` que tienes en la Base de Datos es `latin1` para ese campo.

Tienes 2 opciones; la primera es realizar la consulta sin el `collate`:

```
String Consulta = "select * from usuarios where Usuario ='" + user + "' and Contrasena ='" + pass + "'";
```

La seguna opción es modificar el `COLLATE` de esos campos:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ALTER COLUMN Usuario [TYPE] COLLATE utf8_bin
ALTER TABLE usuarios ALTER COLUMN Contrasena [TYPE] COLLATE utf8_bin
```

O bien de toda la base de datos:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase COLLATE utf8_bin
```