# Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo un `SELECT` con diferentes selects dentro de él, pero al hacerlo me salta el siguiente error

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

```
SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE TRUE 
    AND `DATE` >= '2010-09-08' 
    AND `DATE` <= '2020-10-14' 
    AND ID IN (
    SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE WHERE
        PRODUCT_CODE IN ( 'CR263' )
        )
```

He probado a añadir `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` pero ahora el error que devuelve es

> COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1

```
SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE TRUE 
    AND `DATE` >= '2010-09-08' 
    AND `DATE` <= '2020-10-14' 
    AND ID IN (
    SELECT INVOICE_ID COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci FROM INVOICE_LINE WHERE
        PRODUCT_CODE IN ( 'CR263' )
        )
```

**Tanto la tabla `INVOICE` como `INVOICE_LINE` tiene definido la Collation en `utf8_unicode_ci`**

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14480/146637) pueda servirte

Answer (score 2):

El problema era que, aunque la tabla estuviese en `utf8_unicode_ci`, había un campo en `utf8_spanish_ci`